# How can I open specific project in TortoiseHg workbench from CLI

Tags: tortoisehg

I am using TortoiseHg on MacOS, and would like to open the repository of the project I am working on in workbench from the command-line. I tried providing a directory names:

```
% open -a /Applications/TortoiseHg.app ~/MyProject
% open -a /Applications/TortoiseHg.app ~/MyProject/.hg
```

and also tried specifying just the repository name (as already listed in the repository registry of TortoiseHg):

```
% open -a /Applications/TortoiseHg.app MyProject
```

but TortoiseHg merely opens the workbench without already opening any repository. I have to search the list and double click the repository I want to open.

Is there a way to have workbench automatically open a specific repository when started from the command-line?

Comment: did you mean `% thg open ...` ?

Comment: @StayOnTarget: how can I install the `thg` script/alias on MacOS? I have installed TortoiseHg from a direct DMG download of their website, and tried via `brew` but neither installed a `thg` command-line utility.

Comment: Are you sure its not just a path issue? `thg` may be installed but not in $PATH ?

Comment: What is the location of the `open` command you referenced?  Try `where open` or `which open`

Comment: `% sudo find / -type f -iname 'thg*'` does not find any useful matches so it is not a $PATH problem. The `open` command is the standard MacOS command to open files or applications.